# How a media image entity_reference field in a custom content entity can be set to translatable?

Tags: 8, entities, i18n-l10n, media

I created a media image field in my custom entity content:

```
$fields['image'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
  ->setLabel(t('Promotion image'))
  ->setDescription(t('Recommended image size is 1600x900 pixels.'))
  ->setRevisionable(TRUE)
  ->setTranslatable(TRUE)
  ->setRequired(FALSE)
  ->setSetting('target_type', 'media')
  ->setSetting('handler', 'default:media')
  ->setSettings([
    'handler_settings' => [
      'target_bundles' => [
        'image' => 'image',
      ],
      'sort' => [
        'field' => '_none',
      ],
      'auto_create' => FALSE,
      'auto_create_bundle' => '',
    ],
  ])
  ->setCardinality(1)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
    'settings' => [
      'entity_browser' => 'image_browser',
      'field_widget_display' => 'rendered_entity',
      'field_widget_edit' => TRUE,
      'field_widget_remove' => TRUE,
      'open' => TRUE,
      'selection_mode' => 'selection_append',
      'field_widget_display_settings' => [
        'view_mode' => 'default',
      ],
      'field_widget_replace' => FALSE,
    ],
    'type' => 'entity_browser_entity_reference',
    'weight' => 3,
  ])
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
    'label' => 'hidden',
    'settings' => [
      'target_type' => 'media',
    ],
    'weight' => 3,
  ]);
```

Even though the entity itself, and the field are set to `translatable`, the **ALT** and **TITLE** attributes of the image are not translated.

If I create this field manually in the UI, it works as intended, and gets translated. How could I define this field to be translatable programmatically?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Translating the reference field means you need to replace the media item with a translated version, but it looks more like you want to keep the media item and translate ALT and TITLE in the media entity.

Comment: Good catch, thanks. I intend to make the media image translatable as a whole entity, the image, the ALT and TITLE attributes... Current code example doesn't do that though. This is as much as I could gather from the config files when I manually added and configured the media field as such. Seems i'm missing some more. Any ideas?

Comment: I wouldn't make the reference field translatable then. This can be quite confusing if you have already configured the media type including the image field with the file, title and alt property as translatable.